# Named Set using iif in mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

Ι am trying to make calculated dimension attribute using a named set but I am not very familiar with mdx. I want the attribute to contain a description based on the values of 4 different attributes. What I have tried to use is the following code but it must have invalid syntax (gives an error).

```
create set [pet types]
as

iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].&[Yes],
    iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Cat].&[Yes],
        iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].&[Yes],
            iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Other Pet].&[Yes],
                "Multiple Pets","Cat and Dog"),
        "Cat"),
    iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].&[Yes] 
        and [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].&[Yes],
        "Dog and other Pet","Dog")),
"No Pet")
```

Comment: Strange `mdx` what references are you using to come up with this? Readability needs some work. One obvious problem is that you're attempting to create a Measure not a Set. A Set is a group of members - your script returns a string based on conditions - so is a measure.

Comment: I have used various references and my imagination. Specifically, I had a dax script for a calculated column and I tried to implement it in mdx. I see what you mean about my misunderstanding. So how can I make a calculated column with this logic? A named calculation on DSV doesn't help because case statement doesn't support sets with common members (intersected)

Comment: I use `MDX` to query cubes - I don't get involved with the cube script so might not be much help. If you can abstract your problem to a normal `MDX` script (`WITH...SELECT...FROM...WHERE`) then I can help.

Comment: Just for the safe side: set is not full, "Cat and other Pet" is missed: [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].&[Yes] AND [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Cat].&[Yes] AND [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Other Pet].&[Yes] AND NOT ([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].&[Yes])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve readability (but it decreases scalability) I'd rather use matrix of states with a coefficient of each hierarchy's member:
[image: Pets Matrix]

Than add several members with their weights:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Has Pet Value] as
IIF([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].CurrentMember
 IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].&[Yes],8,0);

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Has Cat Value] as
IIF([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Cat].CurrentMember
 IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Cat].&[Yes],4,0);

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Has Dog Value] as
IIF([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].CurrentMember
 IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].&[Yes],2,0);

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Has Other Pet Value] as
IIF([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Other Pet].CurrentMember
 IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Other Pet].&[Yes],1,0);
```

And last two members: 1) for support, 2) to get desirable result.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Pet Types Value] as
([Measures].[Has Pet Value]
+[Measures].[Has Cat Value]
+[Measures].[Has Dog Value]
+[Measures].[Has Other Pet Value]);

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Pet Types] as
case [Measures].[Pet Types Value]
    when 15 then "Multiple Pets"
    when 14 then "Cat and Dog"
    when 13 then "Cat and other Pet"
    when 12 then "Cat"
    when 11 then "Dog and other Pet"
    when 10 then "Dog"
    else "No Pet" end;
```

Adding another dimension/hierarchy for analysis (let's say `[Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Bird].&[Yes]`) may cause adding new member with next weight (16 in this example) and recalculate `[Pet Types Value]` and `[Pet Types]`.

Comment: upp-ed I like this (especially the weights chosen)

Comment: @whytheq, I also thought about increasing scalability and automation of this solution. Smth like: add a table with identity column and desirable members (cat, dog etc.), than calculate weight in DSV as 2^ID and add it like property. Finally, use this properties instead of adding Has_Animal_Value measures. But manual editing [Measures].[Pet Types] is unavoidable.

Comment: The trick with the sum was very helpful. I used it to construct the dimension attribute I was needed.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about cube scripts as I don't play with those but doing some Googling got the below.

Please test without the `AND` as I think that will also cause an error.

Also rather than "No Pet" I'd suggest changing this to null so the measure becomes sparse as that is one of the points of `olap`.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.PetType 
AS 
'
iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].CurrentMember IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].&[Yes],
    iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Cat].CurrentMember IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Cat].&[Yes],
        iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].CurrentMember IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].&[Yes],
            iif([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Other Pet].CurrentMember IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Other Pet].&[Yes],
                "Multiple Pets","Cat and Dog"),
        "Cat"),
    iif(([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].CurrentMember IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Dog].&[Yes]) 
        AND ([Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].CurrentMember IS [Vw Cube Customer Dim].[Has Pet].&[Yes]),
        "Dog and other Pet","Dog")),
"No Pet")
'
```